# Git pre-receive hook to prevent merge to master if not already in develop branch

Tags: bash, git, gitlab, githooks

Our git process looks like this. The primary branch is master, off of which we create feature branches. When we think we're done with a feature, we merge it into the develop branch and it gets built to an integration environment for testing. Once it's tested, we submit a MR from the feature branch to master.

I'm trying to make a pre-receive git hook that will prevent a MR from being accepted unless the branch has been merged into develop and therefore integration tested. But I'm struggling to figure out how to do that with the information I have available in the hook.

The current script I have is below

```sh
while read oldrev newrev refname; do
    # Get the name of the branch that HEAD is pointing to
    headbranch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
    # Get the current branch name
    branch=$(echo $refname | sed 's/refs\/heads\///g')
    # During a merge request both the branch and head branch will be master
    if [[ "$branch" == "master" && "$headbranch" == "master" ]]; then
        # Grab the PREVIOUS revision of the current revision as this is the last commit before the current merge commit
        prevrev=$(git rev-list -2 $newrev | sed -n '2 p')
        # Check that revision is in the develop branch already, otherwise reject the commit
        $(git merge-base --is-ancestor $prevrev develop)
        if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
            echo "The branch has not been merged with \"develop\" or you have not pushed \"develop\" to the remote server." && exit 1
        fi
    fi
done
```

This works *sometimes*, but other times it fails because both the `newrev` and `prevrev` are some random hash related to the merge request and neither of them are in any history. I can't think of a way to differentiate between these MR hashes that I don't care about and actual hashes with code commits that just haven't been merged yet.

Is there another way to do this or is this impossible?

**Notes**: I also expect the script to reject direct commits to master.

Comment: You could test if the hash is part of the commits of the dev branch.

Comment: That's what the line `$(git merge-base --is-ancestor $prevrev develop)` does. The problem is that `$newrev` and even `$prevrev` might not be if it's not a fast-forward merge. They are _new_ commits made by Git as part of the merge process so by definition they won't be in develop. I need to find out if the latest commit on the _branch_ being merged is in develop, but I don't have a way to find that out.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7262307/10871900) help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your hook code is definitely a bit wrong. :-)

A perfect solution is very difficult for one reason: `git push` can receive *multiple update requests* in a single push.  As you said:

> I'm trying to make a pre-receive git hook that will prevent a MR from being accepted unless the branch has been merged into develop and therefore integration tested.

Let's talk about the most general case first, and then more specific cases.  Suppose a push request says:

- change `develop` to point to commit `a123456`—it's currently `a654321`;
- change the HEAD-ref branch (let's say that's `master`) to point to commit `b789abc`; and
- update MR1234 (`refs/merges/1234` perhaps) to point to commit `c765432`.

Now suppose further that `a654321` (the *current* value of `develop`) contains `c765432`.  That is, MR1234 *was* in `develop` before.  It's therefore been run through some sort of integration testing.  Apparently this failed, because `develop` is being *retracted* to `a123456`, which is "before" `a654321` so that *after* this push finishes, `a654321` *won't* be in `develop` any more.

Meanwhile, somewhere in the ancestry of `b789abc`, commit `a123456` exists.  That's the old MR1234—the one that's being replaced in this push.

Personally, I have no idea what to do with this mess.  Fortunately, a *pre-receive* hook has only two options: accept it all, or reject it all.  An *update* hook—the one in the repository will be used for each of these three updates, if the pre-receive hook allows them—has the option to accept or reject one request at a time, but does not get this kind of global information.

Given that you're using a system in which one makes merge requests, waits for some sort of CI/CD system to test them, and only then tries to submit them for final processing, the thing to do with *this* kind of push—that's trying to update `master`, `develop`, and some merge request all at once—is just to reject it, with a message of the form: *don't do everything at once, I need to handle each request one at a time*.

This requires either mixing some logic together or doing several passes.  You can use whichever method you prefer, but doing multiple passes in a Git hook is a little tricky, because Git sends this data down a pipe.<sup>1</sup>  This means you only get to *read* it once.  You can read and save it, and then do multiple passes over the data.  In the shell, you'd typically do that by making your own temporary file:

```
TF=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $TF" 0 1 2 3 15
cat > $TF
```

and now you can read `$TF` as many times as you like.  Reading more than once is less efficient, but easier to get right.

---

<sup>1</sup>I think this is a mistake on Git's part, but that is another issue entirely.

---

Next, a push request can also create a new branch or delete an existing branch.  It can create or delete a tag (or be asked to update one but, except in old versions of Git that accidentally used branch rules on tag names, only if forced).  It can—I think—be used on names that are neither branch nor tag names, too (e.g., `refs/notes/*` names).  We could separate those out and allow pushes that, e.g., both create one tag *and* update one branch.  But for the moment let's just start with "one operation only":

```
count=0
while read line; do : $((count+=1)); done < $TF
if [ $count -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "Only one operation per push, please!" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Next, let's do the same thing you did: figure out what the `HEAD` branch in the receiving bare repository is.  This is the name of the mainline branch (`main`, `master`, etc):

```
headbranch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
```

This command *can* fail, if `HEAD` is detached, or refers to a branch that does not exist yet.  That should never happen but if we want to be really clever we probably should test for that and print something and exit:

```
headbranch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) || {
    echo "detached HEAD - please get an admin to fix me" 1>&2
    exit 1
}
```

Let's add one more thing: the zero hash.  To future-proof against sha256 we'll read the hash of the head ref and turn all the hex values into zeros:

```
zerohash=$(git rev-parse HEAD) || {
    echo "missing HEAD - please get an admin to fix me" 1>&2
    exit 1
}
zerohash=$(echo $zerohash | sed 's/[1-9a-z]/0/g')
```

Now we can read through the update requests and vet them.  For sanity in coding, we probably should make use of shell functions.  We'll define the shell function earlier in the file (so that we can use it) but let's write the code that *uses* it now.  We know there's only one op here because we counted them earlier, but for cleanliness, I'll read them all in a loop again:

```
while read old new hash; do check $old $new $hash; done < $TF
```

We'll have `check` return a status, so let's set that *before* this while loop:

```
exitcode=0
while read old new hash; do
    check $old $new $hash
    status=$?
    if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then exitcode=$status; fi
done < $TF
exit $exitcode
```

Now we need our `check` function.  It will inherit `$headbranch`.  It takes three arguments and returns a status (0 = OK, nonzero = error message sent).  Let's start by seeing whether the request is for a *branch* name or not:

```
check() {
    local old=$1 new=$2 ref=$3
    local shortref

    case $ref in
    refs/heads/*) shortref=${ref#refs/heads/};;
    *) return 0;;
    esac
```

The `case` construct allows a lot of testing with glob expressions, which is convenient here.  (In very old versions of the shell, it's also faster than `if`, though if you're using bash or a modern `sh`, there's no speed difference.)

Now we need to see if the branch is the one of interest (`master` or whatever the main branch is).  If not, we just allow this.

```
    if [ "$shortref" != "$headbranch" ]; then return 0; fi
```

At this point we're updating `master` or whatever the head ref is.  We will now demand that (1) this is a merge commit and (2) the *second* parent of the merge commit is on the first-parent list of `develop`.  Unless, perhaps the push is being done by some appropriate admin (I'll leave that test to you, especially since "who is actually doing this push" can be very difficult to test—it depends entirely on the rest of your server framework).  So:

```
    # if person doing push is admin: return 0
    # Make sure this is neither creation nor deletion
    local op
    case $old,$new in
    $zerohash,*) op=create;;
    *,$zerohash) op=delete;;
    *) op=update;;
    esac
    if [ $op != update ]; then
        echo "not allowed to create or delete $headbranch" 1>&2
        return 1
    fi

    # require that this add exactly 1 2-parent merge commit: find
    # all parents with ^@ suffix and set them as our $1, $2, ..., $n
    set -- $(git rev-parse $new^@)
    case $# in
    0) echo "root commit: forbidden on $headbranch" 1>&2; return 1;;
    1) echo "not a merge commit: forbidden on $headbranch" 1>&2; return 1;;
    2) ;;
    *) echo "$#-parent merge: forbidden on $headbranch" 1>&2; return 1;;

    # Now $1 is parent #1, which had better be the OLD commit;
    # $2 is the commit being merged, which needs to be in the
    # history of `develop`.
    if [ $1 != $old ]; then
        echo "this push adds more than one commit to $headbranch," 1>&2
        echo "which is not allowed: one commit at a time only please" 1>&2
        return 1
    fi

    if ! git merge-base --is-ancestor $2 develop; then
        echo "this push tries to merge $2," 1>&2
        echo "which is not present in branch `develop` on the server;" 1>&2
        echo "this is not allowed"
        return 1
    fi

    # all tests passed
    return 0
}
```

Note: none of the above is tested.  Many of these bits are fragments from standard hooks, though, so it should all at least be "close".  To test it, clone some repo and run some sample inputs through it on its standard input.